# Netbeans Editor Library?

Tags: java, netbeans, editor, syntax-highlighting

Netbeans seems to say in several places that it supports a library to just host the "Netbeans editor" widget in some other program.  It has some weird documentation that seems to say a lot, but doesn't really say much about how to use it: http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-netbeans-modules-editor-lib2/architecture-summary.html

I can't seem to find any download for the "Netbeans editor library" (1 or 2), and the documentation they provide says to download the *entire mercurial repository*, which doesn't really help me, since it doesn't tell me what is part of this "library" and what is not.

If someone could point me to a download for this library, or some minimal documentation about how to use it, that would be great.  I've already seen the blog post [here](http://www.antonioshome.net/kitchen/netbeans/nbms-standalone.php), but it doesn't really help with *getting* the library, and it seems to be talking about classes which I can't find in the Netbeans sources I downloaded (Maybe a different version?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NetBeans editor is part of the NetBeans *platform* and thus is part of either NetBeans IDE itself or the separate platform download.

The platform itself can be downloaded from here: http://platform.netbeans.org/platform-get.html

But I'm not sure if you can use a platform module outside a platform application. If that should be possible it most probably will be a very complicated thing to do.

You might want to have a look at this article:
http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-htmleditor.html which explains how to create a standalone HTML editor based on the NetBeans platform by simply customizing the platform.